How do we explain the problem of Quantum Particle curvature?
One of the things that is important about unifying GR and QFT is to answer the question of how Quantum particles (with mass and energy) curve spacetime when they are probabilistic. I haven't managed to find an answer or even a prediction to a solution to this problem. Quantum particles also can't just "not curve spacetime" as mass curve spacetime is an integral part and is verified experimentally and integral in cosmological properties. So How can we find an accurate prediction to this problem - I am debating between two main ideas - whether they just don't curve spacetime or whether the curvature is probabilistic

Are you asking for a theory of quantum gravity? If so, we don’t have one yet.

I am asking about a prediction such as how string theory is a prediction about how we can make theory of everything to a problem about Quantum Particles curving spacetime as we know spacetime curvature is experimentally confirmed.

And string theory if it is at least a candidate for theory of everything should have at least a prediction to this problem

It does. The graviton is hypothesized to be the excitation of a spin-2 tensor field that couples to the metric tensor, thus producing a perfectly-fine theory of quantum gravidynamics. The only issue is we haven’t observed gravitons yet; future particle accelerator and other projects hope to detect them. That’s pretty key to string theory. Is that what you were looking for?

How would the graviton explain this problem - how Quantum Particles have mass and should curve spacetime yet have probabilistic nature. Would the graviton be able to explain it?

Yes, it would. There isn’t necessarily an issue with spacetime being representable as a quantum object, it’s just without QG you can’t effectively tell what happens at really really small scales where those effects are magnified, and there doesn’t seem to be a mechanism by which mass would curve spacetime. If the graviton field exists, it would provide a physical mechanism for other particles to affect spacetime and resolve all of it.

What would be the mechanism in how graviton field lets (quantum probabilistic) particles interact with spacetime

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Asking what would a solution look like to this very big open area of research in physics is way too broad and unfocused imho. If you can focus your question to ask something more like "How can the specific theory X deal with specific issue Y" it will be better.

@user154560 "how Quantum particles (with mass and energy) curve spacetime when they are probabilistic" - They are not. Particles are described by the wave function, which is not probabilistic. Only measurement is. When you don't measure, the particle exists everywhere at once as a wave (see the double-slit experiment). Since gravity would be caused by the wave function, the problem you are asking about does not exist. Would the probabilistic nature of measurement also apply to gravity? Sure, but this does not cause any paradoxes just like probabilistic measurement in any other field.
